# Flutter - How to filter products using API?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, filter, controller

I'm a flutter beginner. I create a filter screen. I have created products model, remote services, and controllers.

**How to use those controllers and models on the filter page?**

The filter page has Gender, Age, Availability, and Price.

How to filter products with these filters by using controllers and models?

Remote service:

```
Future<Response?> filterProducts() async {
    var uri = '$_url/product-filter';
    print(uri);
    // String token = box.read('token');

    // dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token";
    try {
      final response = await dio.get(uri);
      print("Filtered Products: ${response.data}");
      return response;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.response!.data.toString());
      return e.response!.data;
    }
  }
```

Controller code:

```
  final filter = FilterProductsModel().obs;
Future filterProducts() async {
    dio.Response? response = await remoteServices.filterProducts();

    if (response!.statusCode == 200) {
      filter(FilterProductsModel.fromJson(response.data));
    }
  }
```

Models:

```
class FilterProductsModel {
  Collection? collection;

  FilterProductsModel({this.collection});

  FilterProductsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    collection = json['collection'] != null
        ? new Collection.fromJson(json['collection'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.collection != null) {
      data['collection'] = this.collection!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Collection {
  String? handle;
  Products? products;

  Collection({this.handle, this.products});

  Collection.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    handle = json['handle'];
    products = json['products'] != null
        ? new Products.fromJson(json['products'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['handle'] = this.handle;
    if (this.products != null) {
      data['products'] = this.products!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Products {
  List<Edges>? edges;

  Products({this.edges});

  Products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['edges'] != null) {
      edges = <Edges>[];
      json['edges'].forEach((v) {
        edges!.add(new Edges.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.edges != null) {
      data['edges'] = this.edges!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Edges {
  Node? node;
  List<ImageUrl>? imageUrl;

  Edges({this.node, this.imageUrl});

  Edges.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    node = json['node'] != null ? new Node.fromJson(json['node']) : null;
    if (json['imageUrl'] != null) {
      imageUrl = <ImageUrl>[];
      json['imageUrl'].forEach((v) {
        imageUrl!.add(new ImageUrl.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.node != null) {
      data['node'] = this.node!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.imageUrl != null) {
      data['imageUrl'] = this.imageUrl!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Node {
  String? handle;
  List<String>? tags;
  bool? availableForSale;
  String? productType;
  String? vendor;
  PriceRange? priceRange;
  Products? images;

  Node(
      {this.handle,
      this.tags,
      this.availableForSale,
      this.productType,
      this.vendor,
      this.priceRange,
      this.images});

  Node.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    handle = json['handle'];
    tags = json['tags'].cast<String>();
    availableForSale = json['availableForSale'];
    productType = json['productType'];
    vendor = json['vendor'];
    priceRange = json['priceRange'] != null
        ? new PriceRange.fromJson(json['priceRange'])
        : null;
    images =
        json['images'] != null ? new Products.fromJson(json['images']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['handle'] = this.handle;
    data['tags'] = this.tags;
    data['availableForSale'] = this.availableForSale;
    data['productType'] = this.productType;
    data['vendor'] = this.vendor;
    if (this.priceRange != null) {
      data['priceRange'] = this.priceRange!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.images != null) {
      data['images'] = this.images!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class PriceRange {
  MinVariantPrice? minVariantPrice;
  MinVariantPrice? maxVariantPrice;

  PriceRange({this.minVariantPrice, this.maxVariantPrice});

  PriceRange.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    minVariantPrice = json['minVariantPrice'] != null
        ? new MinVariantPrice.fromJson(json['minVariantPrice'])
        : null;
    maxVariantPrice = json['maxVariantPrice'] != null
        ? new MinVariantPrice.fromJson(json['maxVariantPrice'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.minVariantPrice != null) {
      data['minVariantPrice'] = this.minVariantPrice!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.maxVariantPrice != null) {
      data['maxVariantPrice'] = this.maxVariantPrice!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class MinVariantPrice {
  String? amount;

  MinVariantPrice({this.amount});

  MinVariantPrice.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    amount = json['amount'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['amount'] = this.amount;
    return data;
  }
}

class Edges1 {
  Node? node;

  Edges1({this.node});

  Edges1.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    node = json['node'] != null ? new Node.fromJson(json['node']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.node != null) {
      data['node'] = this.node!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Node1 {
  String? src;
  String? id;

  Node1({this.src, this.id});

  Node1.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    src = json['src'];
    id = json['id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['src'] = this.src;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    return data;
  }
}

class ImageUrl {
  String? url;

  ImageUrl({this.url});

  ImageUrl.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    url = json['url'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['url'] = this.url;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Filter code:

```
Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20),
                      child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text('BY PRICE',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  letterSpacing: 0.6,
                                )),
                          ]),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text('BHD4 - BHD33',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  letterSpacing: 0.6,
                                )),
                          ]),
                    ),
                    SfRangeSliderTheme(
                      data: SfRangeSliderThemeData(
                        tooltipBackgroundColor: const Color(0xff6fedf6),
                        tooltipTextStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          textStyle: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            letterSpacing: 1,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: SfRangeSlider(
                          values: _values,
                          min: 4.0,
                          max: 66.0,
                          activeColor: Colors.white,
                          inactiveColor: const Color(0xffcbcbcb),
                          numberFormat: NumberFormat('BHD'),
                          enableTooltip: true,
                          onChanged: (dynamic newValues) {
                            setState(() {
                              _values = newValues;
                            });
                          }),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20),
                      child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text('AVAILABILITY',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  letterSpacing: 0.8,
                                )),
                          ]),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 20),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Wrap(
                                spacing: 8,
                                runSpacing: 8,
                                children: items1
                                    .map(
                                      (e) => FilterChip(
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                          ),
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                          selectedColor:
                                              const Color(0xff6fedf6),
                                          label: Container(
                                            height: 46,
                                            width: 100,
                                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                                            child: Text(e),
                                          ),
                                          labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                            textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontSize: 14,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                              letterSpacing: 0.5,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          selected: availability.contains(e),
                                          onSelected: (bool value) {
                                            if (availability.contains(e)) {
                                              availability.remove(e);
                                            } else {
                                              availability.add(e);
                                            }
                                            setState(() {});
                                          }),
                                    )
                                    .toList(),
                              ),
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20),
                      child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text('GENDER',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  letterSpacing: 0.8,
                                )),
                          ]),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 20),
                      child: Wrap(
                        spacing: 8,
                        runSpacing: 8,
                        children: items2
                            .map(
                              (e) => FilterChip(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  ),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  selectedColor: const Color(0xff6fedf6),
                                  label: Container(
                                    height: 46,
                                    width: 50,
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Text(e),
                                  ),
                                  labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      letterSpacing: 0.5,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  selected: gender.contains(e),
                                  onSelected: (bool value) {
                                    if (gender.contains(e)) {
                                      gender.remove(e);
                                    } else {
                                      gender.add(e);
                                    }
                                    setState(() {});
                                  }),
                            )
                            .toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20),
                      child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text('AGE',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  letterSpacing: 0.8,
                                )),
                          ]),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 20),
                      child: Wrap(
                        spacing: 8,
                        runSpacing: 15,
                        children: items3
                            .map(
                              (e) => FilterChip(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  ),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  selectedColor: const Color(0xff6fedf6),
                                  label: Container(
                                    height: 46,
                                    width: 80,
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Text(e),
                                  ),
                                  labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      letterSpacing: 0.5,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  selected: age.contains(e),
                                  onSelected: (bool value) {
                                    if (age.contains(e)) {
                                      age.remove(e);
                                    } else {
                                      age.add(e);
                                    }
                                    setState(() {});
                                  }),
                            )
                            .toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
```